# Unique key, INSERT IGNORE and table partitioning

Tags: php, mysql, sql, partitioning, database-partitioning

So I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `slots` (
 `customerid` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `orderid` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `queueid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `item_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `variable1` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `variable2` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `variable3` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `variable4` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `variable5` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `variable6` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `variable7` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `variable8` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `variable9` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY `queueid` (`queueid`),
 UNIQUE KEY (`customerid`,`orderid`),
 KEY `orderid` (`orderid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25883472 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

That I want to partition horizontally by customerid. The problem is that customerid and orderid must form a unique combination -> I've created an unique key for that and use INSERT IGNORE to ignore inserts that would result in a duplicate row.

Would that still work with partitioned table? Or it wouldn't help with my insert speed (I am partitioning the table to achieve higher INSERT speed  but I still need to watch out to not insert one row multiple times ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The partitioning docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html) have this to say;

> All columns used in the partitioning expression for a partitioned table must be part of every unique key that the table may have.

In other words, it will work as long as you're partitioning on `customerid`, `orderid` or both, otherwise your unique key is invalid.

Comment: So, if I understand this right, even if the unique key is based on two columns - I need to use just one of those columns when partitioning?

Comment: @user3010273 If you have a unique index, the only allowed partitions are on any subset of that index's columns. That is, if your unique index is on `a,b`, you can partition on `a`, `b` or `a,b`, but not `a,d`.

Answer (score 2):

In this case if you want to partition based on customerId & also want to keep UNIQUE KEY on customerId & orderId

**Add customerId to your PK**

[MySQL doc says](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html)

```
every unique key on the table must use every column in the table's partitioning expression. (This also includes the table's primary key, since it is by definition a unique key.
```

So customerId should be part of both UNIQUE KEY as well PRIMARY KEY.